# Pulling all dates that fall on specific date of the week in a year - Java

Tags: java, date

Been wrestling with this problem for a while, would love some input.

The problem I want to solve collects all of the dates in one specific year which fall on a particular day of the week, for example, every Tuesday in 2014. The dates are stored in an `ArrayList<Date>`. This list is then returned.

Also have to validate to make sure the year is not 0 and the day of the week submitted must be a number between 1-7.

If there are any issues, I would love to know what I have screwed up.

```
public List<Date> getDatesforDayOfWeek(int year, int dayOfWeek) throws InvalidDateException, ParseException {

    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (year <= 0 || (1 > dayOfWeek && dayOfWeek > 7)) {

        throw new InvalidDateException("Year or day of week is invalid.");

    } else {

        Calendar newCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        newCal.set(YEAR, year);
        newCal.set(DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);



        while (newCal.get(YEAR) < year + 1) {

            int currentDayOfWeek = newCal.get(DAY_OF_WEEK);

            Date newDate = null;
            if (currentDayOfWeek >= dayOfWeek) {

                int dayOfMonth = newCal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH);
                String strDayOfMonth = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String strYear = String.valueOf(year);

                DateUtility d1 = new DateUtility();
                Date passDate = newCal.getTime();

                String weekDay = d1.getWeekDayNameAbbreviation(passDate);
                String monthAbbreviation = d1.getMonthAbbreviation(passDate);


                String finalString = new String();

                finalString.concat(weekDay).concat(" ").
                        concat(monthAbbreviation).concat(" ").
                        concat(strDayOfMonth).concat(" ").
                        concat(strYear);

                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd YYYY");
                Date theDate = format.parse(finalString);

                dateList.add(theDate);
            }
            newCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

    }
    return (dateList);
}
```

Comment: start with FIRST tuesday of that year and keep adding `7` days until you see change of year

Comment: @JigarJoshi I thought the same thing, but maybe the TC is worried about years like 1582?

Comment: what is special about 1582 @Durandal ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi There was a transition from julian to gregorian, skipping like ten days in march: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar

Comment: @Jigar Gregorian Calendar reform.  Thursday, October 4 was followed by Friday, October 15.

Comment: @Durandal [February 30 1712 (in Sweden)](http://europeanhistory.about.com/library/bldyk2.htm).

Comment: Even in 1582, it seems like starting with the first Tuesday and repeatedly adding 7 days would work just fine, no? As long as you use `Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)`, it should still tell you that Oct 2 was a Tuesday, and the next Tuesday was Oct 19.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was going to do that, but was thinking more about just getting the program to run before optimizing the code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question fails to specify which is first day of the week, but things are further complicated by your method for testing the current day of the week. Let's start with validating days of the week by using the `Calendar` standard,

```
private static boolean isValidDayOfWeek(int dayOfWeek) {
    switch (dayOfWeek) {
    // Seven days of the week.
    case Calendar.SUNDAY: case Calendar.MONDAY: case Calendar.TUESDAY: 
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY: case Calendar.THURSDAY: case Calendar.FRIDAY:
    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It then follows that we can do something like,

```
public static List<Date> getDatesforDayOfWeek(int year, int dayOfWeek) {
    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (year <= 0 || !isValidDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Calendar newCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        newCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        newCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        // First, let's loop until we're at the correct day of the week.
        while (newCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != dayOfWeek) {
            newCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        // Now, add the Date to the List. Then add a week and loop (stop
        // when the year changes).
        do {
            dateList.add(newCal.getTime());
            newCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
        } while (newCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year);
    }
    return dateList;
}
```

Leaving us with `main()`. So, to get every Tuesday in 2014 you could then use -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Date> tuesdays = getDatesforDayOfWeek(2014, Calendar.TUESDAY);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    for (Date d : tuesdays) {
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't DAY_OF_WEEK only allow for day numbers 1-7, as there are only 7 days in the week. Each number represents a day of the week, 1 being Monday. That's why I tried to validate in that way. Thanks for all the other help though! Still getting to grips with java again.

Comment: @TheCrownedPixel Per the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY) Javadoc, 1 is `SUNDAY`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
startOfYear                                              // `Year.of( 2019 ).atDay( 1 )` gets the first day of the year.
.datesUntil( startOfYear.plusYears( 1 ) )                // Generate a stream of incrementing `LocalDate` objects.
.filter(                                                 // Pull out the dates that are a Tuesday.
    t -> t.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) 
)
.collect( Collectors.toList() )                          // Return results in a `List` of `LocalDate` objects.
```

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time work defines Monday as the first day of [week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), identified by number 1. Sunday is 7.

## Avoid j.u.Date & .Calendar

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. They have been supplanted in Java 8 by the new java.time package. That package was inspired by Joda-Time, an alternative that remains an active viable project with some advantages.

Both Joda-Time and java.time use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by default.

## Date-Only

For this Question, we need only dates, not time-of-day or time zones. Both Joda-Time and java.time offer a LocalDate class for this purpose.

## *java.time*

Use `Year.of` and `LocalDate::plusYears` to determine the bounds of a year, yielding a pair of `LocalDate` objects for each first-day-of-year.

```
LocalDate startOfYear = Year.of( 2019 ).atDay( 1 );  // Determine first day of the year.
LocalDate startOfFollowingYear = startOfYear.plusYears( 1 );
```

Loop, incrementing the date one day at a time. If that date happens to be a Tuesday, add it to our collection.

```
LocalDate localDate = startOfYear;
List < LocalDate > tuesdays = new ArrayList <>( 55 ); // Set initialCapacity to maximum number of tuesdays in a year. Probably 53, but I'll go with 55 for good measure.
while ( localDate.isBefore( startOfFollowingYear ) )
{
    if ( localDate.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) )
    {
        tuesdays.add( localDate );
    }
    // Set up the next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
System.out.println( tuesdays );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/08d0rd).

> [2019-01-01, 2019-01-08, 2019-01-15, 2019-01-22, 2019-01-29, 2019-02-05, 2019-02-12, 2019-02-19, 2019-02-26, 2019-03-05, 2019-03-12, 2019-03-19, 2019-03-26, 2019-04-02, 2019-04-09, 2019-04-16, 2019-04-23, 2019-04-30, 2019-05-07, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-21, 2019-05-28, 2019-06-04, 2019-06-11, 2019-06-18, 2019-06-25, 2019-07-02, 2019-07-09, 2019-07-16, 2019-07-23, 2019-07-30, 2019-08-06, 2019-08-13, 2019-08-20, 2019-08-27, 2019-09-03, 2019-09-10, 2019-09-17, 2019-09-24, 2019-10-01, 2019-10-08, 2019-10-15, 2019-10-22, 2019-10-29, 2019-11-05, 2019-11-12, 2019-11-19, 2019-11-26, 2019-12-03, 2019-12-10, 2019-12-17, 2019-12-24, 2019-12-31]

Or get fancy with [functional lambda syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Java). The [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)) method generates a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/), in Java 9 and later. Then filter the stream by a match on [`DayOfWeek.TUESDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#TUESDAY).

```
LocalDate startOfYear = Year.of( 2019 ).atDay( 1 );
Stream < LocalDate > stream = startOfYear.datesUntil( startOfYear.plusYears( 1 ) );
List < LocalDate > tuesdays = stream.filter( t -> t.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

## *Joda-Time*

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.4 for collecting all the Tuesdays in a year.

```
int year = 2014; 
String input = year + "-01-01";
LocalDate localDateInput = LocalDate.parse( input );
LocalDate firstTuesday = localDateInput.withDayOfWeek ( DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY );
LocalDate tuesday = firstTuesday;  // for incrementing by week.
List<LocalDate> list = new ArrayList<>();
while ( tuesday.getYear() == year ) {
  list.add( tuesday );
  tuesday.plusWeeks( 1 );
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem lies in this condition

```
if (currentDayOfWeek >= dayOfWeek) {
```

since that will count any day that is "higher" than the day you want. If you pass `3`, it will also count any day that is higher than `3`, which isn't what you want.

the condition should be

```
if (currentDayOfWeek == dayOfWeek) {
```

I also recommend you use [Calendar getTime method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) instead of parsing a `String` to get your `Date`.